# How to add data from array in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am fetching data from API and I want to add that data in dropdown select. I am working with ReactJs

```
class ShowStudents extends React.Component {
  state = {
    nationalities: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setNationalities()
  }

  setNationalities = () => {
    fetch('/students/getData')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        let tempNationalities = data.data.map(product => {
          return { value: product.nationality, display: product.nationality }
        })
        this.setState({ nationalities[...this.state.nationalities, ...tempNationalities ] })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-4">
            {this.state.nationalities}
          </div>
          <select>
            {this.state.nationalities.map((nationality) => <option key={nationality.value} value={nationality.value}>{nationality.display}</option>)}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
export default ShowStudents
```

I need to add values from tempNationalities in state.nationatilites. When I run this a get an error: "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {value, display}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead" . How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues:

```
this.setState({nationalities[...this.state.nationalities,...tempNationalities ] })
```

Should be:

```
this.setState({nationalities: [...this.state.nationalities,...tempNationalities ] })
```

Also you seem to be rendering a raw array of objects here:

```
<div className="col-md-4">
  {this.state.nationalities}
</div>
```

Instead of using map or something similar to create components, which you do a few lines later. I think the error that you are seeing has to do with the above div containing an array of objects instead of components.